# Best way to calculate duration of the event in MySQL / SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, events, sqlalchemy

Entity's events are stored in the following way:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'))
    mode = db.Column(db.Integer)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0, server_default=db.text('0'))
```

Record is added at the start of event, without the duration of course. If the previous event of different mode exists, then it's duration needs to be set.

Example with one `mode` of `None`, end result asserted:

```
assert [(x.timestamp, x.duration, x.mode) for x in events] == [
    (datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 22, 10, 23, 45), 120L, 0L),
    (datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 22, 10, 25, 45), 172800L, 1L),
    (datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 23, 10, 25, 45), 0L, None),
    (datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 24, 10, 25, 45), 0L, 2L)
]
```

Durations are used in involved statistical reports, so it's probably better to have them stored. Events are otherwise read-only after creation (except maybe for setting duration later), table of events is kind of a log. Another assumption is, that small durations do not matter that much, so if some burst of short events occurs, it does not hurt near-zero durations are not recorded, however, long events must have durations (unless event not ended yet). This, of course, is still valid concurrency issue.

What is the best way to (possibly) update the old event with duration?

Some options, which come to my mind are:

1. Call a class method from `__init__`, which queries for the previous event of the same entity and if found sets its duration
2. Use SQLAlchemy's events to cause action on addition of new Event
3. Some clever table arrangement, which calculates duration at the same level of efficiency as stored duration

Comment: Just as an alternate idea, given MySQL 8 one could `"timestamp" - lag("timestamp") over (partition by entity_id order by "timestamp")`, but you've expressed that this might not perform.

Comment: Nice new trick, thanks! However, `mode` is there, and it prevents using consequent rows: some rows in-between are ignored as they do not introduce mode change, plus mode = NULL are ignored as well.

Comment: Could you btw provide some sample data of events, with durations as they should be in the end.

Comment: I've added an example. Repeated mode is much less often than NULL mode. (I'd even said, it's not normal to have same non-null mode twice in a row, but it's not a problem)

Comment: Any reason your `Event` model can't simply have `start` and `end` attributes that are `DateTime` Columns? You could just have a duration property on the object to calculate the difference for you. You could even use [hybrid attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) to allow you to issue queries on the calculated value.

Comment: How this will help registering event? Or do you suggest saving one record for start and one for end? If that, how it will help calculate duration?

Answer (score 1):

This is not be the best way, nor very clever, but it allows calculating the durations without materializing them. I thought I'd provide it as a curiosity.

Using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) – coming in MySQL 8 – it is possible to calculate differences between adjacent rows in a given window:

```
SELECT
  id,
  entity_id,
  mode,
  "timestamp",
  CASE
    WHEN NOT same_mode THEN
      COALESCE(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                      "timestamp",
                      LEAD("timestamp") OVER w),
        0)
    ELSE 0
  END AS duration
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    mode IS NULL OR
      LAG(mode) OVER v IS NOT NULL AND
      mode = LAG(mode) OVER v AS same_mode
  FROM event
  WINDOW v AS (PARTITION BY entity_id ORDER BY "timestamp")) e
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY entity_id, same_mode
             ORDER BY "timestamp")
ORDER BY "timestamp", ISNULL(mode), mode;
```

The same in SQLAlchemy:

```
In [3]: lagged_mode = db.func.lag(Event.mode).\
   ...:     over(partition_by=Event.entity_id,
   ...:          order_by=Event.timestamp)

In [4]: subquery = db.session.query(
   ...:         Event,
   ...:         ((Event.mode == None) |
   ...:          (lagged_mode != None) &
   ...:          (Event.mode == lagged_mode)).label('same_mode')).\
   ...:     subquery()

In [5]: event_alias = db.aliased(Event, subquery)

In [6]: led_timestamp = db.func.lead(event_alias.timestamp).\
   ...:     over(partition_by=(event_alias.entity_id,
   ...:                        subquery.c.same_mode),
   ...:          order_by=event_alias.timestamp)

In [7]: query = db.session.query(
   ...:         event_alias,
   ...:         db.case(
   ...:             [(~subquery.c.same_mode,
   ...:               db.func.coalesce(
   ...:                   db.func.timestampdiff(db.text('second'),
   ...:                                         event_alias.timestamp,
   ...:                                         led_timestamp),
   ...:                   0))],
   ...:             else_=0).label('duration')).\
   ...:     order_by(event_alias.timestamp,
   ...:              db.func.isnull(event_alias.mode),
   ...:              event_alias.mode)
   ...:
```

Using a recent enough version of SQLAlchemy it would be possible to map `duration` as a [query-time SQL expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes), then provided by the above query.

Comment: Come to think of it, this is going to trip over (read: fail), if a sequence of modes is as follows: 1 - null - 2 - null - 2 - null - 3.

Comment: I think it's an interesting answer, but too high-tech to be the basis for further queries (like, averaging over total times spent in certain modes). I can certainly upvote it, but I am more and more thinking materialization is justified here. Thanks!

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.